# DataClassWizard after upgrading to python3.11 is not working as expected

Tags: flask, python-dataclasses, python-3.11

```
Consider this following code:
@dataclass
class Subjects(JSONWizard):
    subjectName: str =None
    subjectExpert: str = None
    subjectScore: float = None
@dataclass
class Student(JSONWizard):
    studentName: str
    studentId: str
    subjects: list[Subjects] = None
    teachers: list = None
    paidFee: bool = None
    gender: str = None
    attendancePercentage: float = None
    
sample_record = {
    "studentName":"Naveen", "studentId":"18B91A05L2","Subjects":[{"subjectName":"Telugu","subjectExpert":"Lingeswar","subjectScore":23.5}],
    "teachers":["BhaskarRao","LaxmiKumari","Louis"],"paidFee":True,"gender":"M", "attendancePercentage":98.2
}

dataclass_object: Student = Student.from_dict(sample_record)
print(dataclass_object.studentName)
```

I have ran it in python3.9 and its working fine but in python3.11 I am facing this error:
dataclass_wizard.errors.ParseError: Failure parsing field `None` in class `None`. **Expected a type Any, got NoneType.
value: None
error: Provided type is not currently supported.
unsupported_type: typing.Any**
Can someone help me in understanding whats wrong here!

Answer (score 1):

In the ["typing" section of the release notes for python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#typing) it says:

> Allow subclassing of typing.Any. This is useful for avoiding type checker errors related to highly dynamic class, such as mocks. (Contributed by Shantanu Jain in gh-91154.)

This means that the following code returns `True` in 3.11, whereas in 3.10 it returns `False`:

```
from typing import Any
isinstance(Any, type)  # ***
```

The `dataclass_wizard` attemps to discover the `base_type` of each member through a chain of `elif` statements:

```
if isinstance(base_type, type):
    ...
elif base_type is Any:
    ...  # 3.10 constructs the None here.
...
```

Since the first `if` statement no longer evaluates to `False`, the `base_type` is never discovered and the `dataclass_wizard` fails.

You can easily fix this fresh bug in `dataclass_wizard` by reversing the first two `if` statements:

```
if base_type is Any:
    ...  # 3.10 & 3.11 construct the None here.
elif isinstance(base_type, type):
    ...  
...
```